# What is wrong with this Python 3.8 function?

Tags: python-3.x

The variable *deathmax* is not being reassigned to v['deaths']. Im certain I can find a different way of doing this, but I am just trying to understand why if i were to print *deathmax* within the function it would output 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0. Thanks in advance :)

```
ans = {'Cuba I': {'Month': 'October', 'Year': 1924, 'Max Sustained Winds': 165, 'Areas Affected': ['Central America', 'Mexico', 'Cuba', 'Florida', 'The Bahamas'], 'Damage': 'Damages not recorded', 'death': 90}, 'San Felipe II Okeechobee': {'Month': 'September', 'Year': 1928, 'Max Sustained Winds': 160, 'Areas Affected': ['Lesser Antilles', 'The Bahamas', 'United States East Coast', 'Atlantic Canada'], 'Damage': 100000000.0, 'death': 4000}}

deathmax = 0
def maxdeaths(ans):
    for k,v in ans.items():
        if v['death'] >= deathmax:
            print(type(v['death']))
            deathmax == v['death']
    return deathmax


maxdeaths(ans)
```

Comment: `deathmax = v['death']` is how you assign variables. Also, you won't be able to change the value of the (global) `deathmax` variable without putting `global deathmax` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

`deathmax == v['death']`

You're not assigning to `deathmax`, you're comparing its value to what's stored in `v['death']`. Remove one of the equal signs to make it into an assignment.